# Pandas: Replace a string with 'other' if it is not present in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame, df, with column 'Class'

```
    Class
0   Individual
1   Group
2   A
3   B
4   C
5   D
6   Group
```

I would like to replace everything apart from Group and Individual with 'Other', so the final data frame is

```
    Class
0   Individual
1   Group
2   Other
3   Other
4   Other
5   Other
6   Group
```

The dataframe is huge, with over 600 K rows. What is the best way to optimally look for values other than 'Group' and 'Individual' and replace them with 'Other'?

I have seen examples for replace, such as:

```
df['Class'] = df['Class'].replace({'A':'Other', 'B':'Other'})
```

but since the sheer amount of unique values i have are too many i cannot individually do this. I want to rather just use the exclude subset of 'Group' and 'Individual'.

Comment: if there is only `Group` and `Individual` are present, you can use the condition like replace all if not in `['Group', 'Individual']`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df['Class'] = np.where(df['Class'].isin(['Individual','Group']), df['Class'], 'Other')
print (df)
        Class
0  Individual
1       Group
2       Other
3       Other
4       Other
5       Other
6       Group
```

Another solution (slower):

```
m = (df['Class'] == 'Individual') | (df['Class'] == 'Group')
df['Class'] = np.where(m, df['Class'], 'Other')
```

Another solution:

```
df['Class'] = df['Class'].map({'Individual':'Individual', 'Group':'Group'}).fillna('Other')
```

---

**Performance** (in real data depends of number of replacements):

```
#[700000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
#print (df)

In [208]: %timeit df['Class1'] = np.where(df['Class'].isin(['Individual','Group']), df['Class'], 'Other')
25.9 ms ± 485 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [209]: %timeit df['Class2'] = np.where((df['Class'] == 'Individual') | (df['Class'] == 'Group'), df['Class'], 'Other')
120 ms ± 6.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [210]: %timeit df['Class3'] = df['Class'].map({'Individual':'Individual', 'Group':'Group'}).fillna('Other')
95.7 ms ± 3.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [211]: %timeit df.loc[~df['Class'].isin(['Individual', 'Group']), 'Class'] = 'Other'
97.8 ms ± 6.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Wow! This is excellent :) I have gone with the 3rd solution for now. But will use the first solution in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be:

```
df.loc[~df['Class'].isin(['Individual', 'Group']), 'Class'] = 'Other'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way for example

1. get list of unique items `list = df['Class'].unique()`
2. remove your known class `list.remove('Individual')`....
3. then list all Other rows `df[df.class is in list]`
4. replace class values `df[df.class is in list].class = 'Other'`

Sorry for this pseudo-pseudo code, but principle is same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['Class'].where(df['Class'].isin(['Individual', 'Group']), 'Other', inplace=True)

print(df)

        Class
0  Individual
1       Group
2       Other
3       Other
4       Other
5       Other
6       Group
```

This should be efficient versus `map` + `fillna`:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df['Class'].where(df['Class'].isin(['Individual', 'Group']), 'Other')
# 60.3 ms per loop

%timeit df['Class'].map({'Individual':'Individual', 'Group':'Group'}).fillna('Other')
# 133 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `apply` :

```
df['Class'] = df['Class'].apply(lambda cl : cl if cl in ["Individual","Group"] else "Other"]
```