# Python Pandas - rename a value conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, rename

```
df2 = np.where(df2['color'] != 'blue' | 'red')
```

I want to create one category for many categorical values, such as:

If the color is not blue or red, call the color "other"

Please and thank you <3

Comment: `df['color'] = np.where(df['color'].isin(['blue', 'red']), df['color'], 'Other')` as [jezrael recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51323112/15497888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically halfway there. You just have to provide 2 more parameters to achieve what you want.

```
df2['color'] = np.where((df2['color'] == 'blue') | (df2['color'] == 'red'), df2['color'], 'other')
```

Reading the equality is easier because there is less cognitive load. If the condition is True the `df2['color']` will be selected. If the condition is false for that row `'other'` will be selected

Comment: True. My mind played tricks with me :D Fixed it instantly. Thank you

Comment: Thank you! I tried that way because I have WAY more instances that will become "other," and the few rest will remain the original color.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you can accept the answer I'll appreciate it.